# Windows - copy file from machine A to machine B through Powershell executed from machine B on machine A

Tags: powershell

**Please note:** security is not an issue at all with this application.

I have a "MachineA" that has a file we will call `file.txt`. I need to get this file onto a "MachineB". Here's the catch, this needs to be done by remotely sending an `Invoke-Command` script from MachineB to MachineA to kick back the file.

**What I have tried so far:**
I have setup a shared drive (using `net use`) on MachineB that MachineA can access. This drive is known as `z:\` to MachineA.

I can send this command via `Invoke-Command` from MachineB to MachineA and it will transfer a file from one directory to another directory within MachineA

```
xcopy c:\users\administrator\desktop\file.txt c:\file.txt
```

Now if I send the following command in the same manner from MachineB to MachineA it will complain about not being able to see drive Z.

```
xcopy c:\users\administrator\desktop\file.txt z:\FilesFromVMs\file.txt
```

**Note:** if run the second command directly on MachineA from powershell it will move the file but I need to be able to do this remotely via `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Seems me like you're trying to do this backwards. Why use invoke-command at all when you can complete the whole process on MachineB by using map-drive or UNC pointing to MachineA?

Comment: It needs to be an automated repeatable process done directly from MachineB.

Comment: Yes, run copy command on MachineB.. something like  `xcopy \\machineA\C$\users\administrator\desktop\file.txt C:\file.txt` will copy file from machineA to machineB.

Answer (score -2):

If security is not an issue, maybe try using UNC Paths \MachineA\C$\Users...\ instead of relying on mapped drive letters? Perhaps that'll do the trick.

Comment: when using `xcopy` I get "Invalid drive specification" error sent back from MachineA. When using `Copy-Item` I get "Access is denied".